# How do I remove this tag from twitter message-id 'tag:search.twitter.com,2005:7550668919283712'

Tags: php, mysql, twitter, message

When I store into table the id of any tweet like 'tweet->id', its also stores a tag from twitter with it. The id is stored as

```
tag:search.twitter.com,2005:7550668919283712
```

I need to store only id  i.e. 2005:7550668919283712. How do I remove this tag from being stored into table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ideone.com/xC8tw

```
$arr = preg_split("/,/", "tag:search.twitter.com,2005:7550668919283712");
$str = $arr[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply,

```
str_replace('tag:search.twitter.com,', '', 
  'tag:search.twitter.com,2005:7550668919283712');
```

if the `tag:search.twitter.com,` always remain unchanged

Or use `explode` which perform better than `preg_split`